# Updating Customer records

Tags: import, csv

I was wondering if the CSV import would update customer records or does it just create new ones?

As last time i did an import using dataprofiles using an email address and postcode i already had on the database, the whole database got corrupted

Comment: What information do you want to update for the customers?

Comment: Tax/VAT number for all customers

Comment: First create a dummy account and export customers and try to update the Tax/Vat number for that customer.

Comment: Did you filled in all required fields in your csv?